# PhpStorm does not see php.ini inside the container made via Devilbox. Because of what it is not possible to configure xdebug. How to fix it?

Tags: devilbox

Devilbox creates php.ini files inside docker containers. But it calls them differently: docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini, xxx-devilbox-default-php.ini.

PhpStorm does not see these php.ini files. And gives an error. I attach a screenshot. Because of this, it is not possible to pass validation for configuring xdebug. I can't even change any parameters in php.ini - PhpStorm doesn't see php.ini and changes in it, respectively, too.

And not just PhpStorm. If you go inside the container and run the command:

```
php --ini
```

the following text will be output:

```
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
```

How to configure xdebug in PhpStorm on Devilbox?

[image]